# Set log level for each node in ROS CPP

Tags: roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to set the log level for each node in ROS CPP. The node is defined as follows:

```
ros::init(argc, argv, "my_ros_node");
```

What I am looking for is the CPP version of following command:

```
rospy.init_node('my_ros_node', log_level=rospy.DEBUG)
```

I am using ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. As always thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276242/set-log-level-for-each-node-in-ros-cpp/) by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1744 on 2017-11-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2017-11-19**:
You can set it per package. See: http://wiki.ros.org/rosconsole#Configuration

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2017-11-19**:
@clyde: Thank you very much. I am assuming that there must be a way to do it in CPP. It is possible to do in Python, as I posted above. However I am looking for CPP version. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/rosconsole#Changing_Logger_Levels & #q43397

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2017-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2